If I store a function in a reference object, does it hold its value in re-renders?
I was going through this exercise in React documentation and encountered an exercise where we need to add a condition inside Effect. Challenge 2 of 5
I was thinking if we could do it without Effect and thought of applying reference object and storing the function so it doesn't get changed during render and hence will not depend on it.
I wrote this code and is still not working:


const { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } = React;

function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(true);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if(canMove){
  //   function handleMove(e) {
  //     setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  //   }
  //   window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);
  //   return () => window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);
  //     }
  // }, [canMove]);
  
  if(canMove) {
    ref.current = (e) => {
      setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('pointermove', ref.current);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('pointermove', ref.current);
  }
    
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={canMove}
          onChange={e => setCanMove(e.target.checked)} 
        />
        The dot is allowed to move
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        opacity: 0.6,
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        left: -20,
        top: -20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      }} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

// Render

const container = document.querySelector('#root');

if (container === null) throw new Error('Root container doesn\'t exist');

ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



What I am missing out on logic in this code what I want to achieve.
Also is there any way out to achieve this without useEffect(Just exploring React)?

The problem
When you write it without useEffect you are adding a lot of pointermove event listeners because you updating the position on each pointermove so each time on the line
if(canMove) {

canMove is true. That means that after any pointermove you add new event listener with new function but with same behavior
But when you use useEffect you add new event listener ONLY when the canMove is changed so if you don't wanna use useEffect you need to detect changing of this variable by yourself
Solution:
You need to detect changing of canMove manually and save listener inside of useRef so:

I created variable canMovePrev outside of component to it will not change while rerendering. Of course you can use another useRef or useState or anything else to make same thing I just prefer that way

To not creating the new listener every time I put function directly inside of useRef as inital value. If you want to use null as initial value then you need to add extra check if ref.current is already null or not:
if (ref.current !== null) {
  ref.current = (e) => {
    setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  }
}


The after each rerender I check if actual value of canMove is same as canMovePrev:

If yes then I don't do anything
If no then I update the canMovePrev value for further checks and check:

If canMove is true then I will add event listener but it will add only at first time and on every time after removing listener because when you pass same function for same event it will be added only once
If canMove is false then I remove the event listener





Here is the complete code:


const { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } = React;

let canMovePrev = false;

function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(true);
  const ref = useRef((e) => {
    setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  });
  
  if(canMove !== canMovePrev) {
    canMovePrev = canMove;
    
    const prefix = canMove ? 'add' : 'remove'
    
    window[`${prefix}EventListener`]('pointermove', ref.current);
  }
    
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={canMove}
          onChange={e => setCanMove(e.target.checked)} 
        />
        The dot is allowed to move
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        opacity: 0.6,
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        left: -20,
        top: -20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      }} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

// Render

const container = document.querySelector('#root');

if (container === null) throw new Error('Root container doesn\'t exist');

ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




I was thinking where I went wrong in my code and I found out that though I am using useRef to store the function, I am re-assigning on every render(render due to setPosition) which is changing the reference value of the function. From the first paragraph of your answer and just assigning the function once directly inside useRef instantly solves the problem. There is no need to check for canMovePrev now as in every render we only need to check whether canMove is true. The previous state doesn't matter now.

Here is the StackBlitz link

@Indra Of course exactly in your example you can avoid using canMovePrev BUT you need to know that without checking your code inside if else statements will run every time when you move pointer. So if there be some calculations (may be heavy) they will run a lot of time. For performance lack risks I suggest to you to keep using canMovePrev. BTW If my answer helps you please approve it :)
